# Esp32: Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled

Tags: c++, inheritance, arduino, esp32, virtual-functions

I am trying to figure out why this error is popping up in the serial monitor. I tried to figure out which area of the code is the problem. I am pretty sure that it is this one, because if I remove it the code runs. There are some more ModeClasses but they are almost the same. The only difference is the run function. But I don't think that this is the problem. Display class and Clock class I tried individually and they worked.

That's the error message:

```
//error message
Backtrace:0x40086071:0x3ffb27700x400d215d:0x3ffb2780 0x400d1262:0x3ffb27a0 0x400d12ef:0x3ffb27c0 0x400d13fe:0x3ffb2800 0x400d4019:0x3ffb2820 




ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000

Rebooting...
*!��␄Z�*␁����M�␎�Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40086074  PS      : 0x00060b30  A0      : 0x800d2160  A1      : 0x3ffb2770  
A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000400  A5      : 0x00000000  
A6      : 0x00ff0000  A7      : 0x00000040  A8      : 0x800d2dd4  A9      : 0x3ffb2740  
A10     : 0x3ffb27d5  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x0000000a  A13     : 0x00000001  
A14     : 0x00060320  A15     : 0x00000001  SAR     : 0x00000002  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001d  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x40086074  LEND    : 0x4008607f  LCOUNT  : 0x0000003f
```

```
// thats the ModeClock.h file
#ifndef MODE_CLOCK_H
#define MODE_CLOCK_H

#include <Arduino.h>

#include "Mode.h"
#include "Clock.h"
#include "Display.h"

class ModeClock : public Mode
{
private:
    Clock clock;
    Display display;

public:
    ModeClock(Clock c, Display d)
    {
        clock = c;
        display = d;
    }
    void run() override;
};

#endif
```

Here is the .cpp file for the .h file

```
#include "ModeDate.h"

void ModeDate::run()
{

    display.displayText(clock.getClockDate());
    Serial.print(clock.getClockDate());
}
```

And here also the class Mode that is getting inherited by.

```
#define MODE_H
#ifdef MODE_H

class Mode
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    void virtual run() = 0;
};
#endif
```

I read that it could come from trying to access an invalid memory address. That could happen if you use a pointer wrong. But I'm not using any pointer. Please help me I don't know how to get on with it! I'm really thankful for every tip.

Comment: Hi Neb, welcome to SO. In this case the code that causes the crash is not presented. E.g. ModeClock constructor makes a copy of Clock and Display objects, which may or may not be what you intended, potentially triggering side effects like shallow copy. Please post all involved code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By the way: the cryptic stack traces are decoded by this tool: https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder

Comment: Thanks Tarmo for your answer. It was not intended that the constructor makes a copy of Clock and Display. And that is the problem, because I have an init function, that runs on another object of display. Now on the copy this function didn't run. That causes the error. I am so thankful that you helped me. If you wouldn't were I would never figure the problem out!

Comment: So one last question, is there a way that the constructor makes like an alias or how can I prevent the constructor from coping the object?

Comment: You need to use references. The member objects themselves need to be references, and your constructor needs to take a reference also. Note that there is special syntax for initializing a member reference via a constructor.